# Macro that needs to be more dynamic based on selection

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code and i find myself creating 12 times and modules since I have 12 different colleges, each with a unique names.

I would like to make a bit more dynamic, so when I press a specific textbox (I use textbox's and bind to macros instead of buttons) the code captures that and as in Criteria, have tired to use Shapes.Range(Array("DS")).Select but cant figure out how to include that within the Criterial.

Atm I have made 12 modules and within each below code, changed Criteria:= and each macro is bound to each button, but I think it should be possible to have one code, 12 boxes and depending on which box with what name (I have named them all) the code should do the sorting and the filtering.

I do appreciate your guys help and sorry for being so beginner at this..

If anyone wonders what this workbook dose (I have a lot of modules and macros running ofc for different functions) is, importing data, format it, deleting and cleaning a lot of stuff, then making a dynamic table since the source data can vary for day to day, and then based on filtering on colleges, export as a none vba/macro file (I generate a new sheet with the info I want, export that, save that) then mail it out, delete the sheet, clean everything (my woorkbook).

[image]

```
    Sub SortExport_DS()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("PR11_P3")).Name = "R11 (P3)" & " fram t.o.m. " & Format(Now - 1, "YYYY-MM-DD")
    
    Sheets("PR11_P3").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("PR11_P3_Tabell").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, _
        Criteria1:="S, Daniel"
    Range("PR11_P3_Tabell[#All]").Select
    Selection.Copy
    
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("A1").Select
    
    Dim Table As ListObject
    Set Table = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, _
    Range("A10").CurrentRegion, , xlYes)
        With Table
            .Name = "PR11_P3_Temp_Tabell"
        End With
    Sheets("PR11_P3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A10").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: When you call a macro using a shape on a worksheet, you can use `Application.Caller` to reference the clicked-on shape, so inside your macro you can use (eg) `ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TextFrame2.TextRange.Text` to get the text inside the clicked-on shape, or just use `Application.Caller` if your shapes have useful names.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll experiment with this. But I still cant figure out how to make "textframe" dynamic, I'm trying to avoid a new modul and a new sub for each and every textbox(frame). would land in having one module and and one sub for all this instead of 12 different ones.

Comment: You link all the shapes to the same Sub.  I might be misunderstanding the problem here

Comment: done that, basically above code is in one module, 12 subs, the only different is name of each sub and the value in Criteria1, and this is what I mean not being a correct way to approach this. I should have one module (i do now) but also just one macro(in onw sub), in that macro approach the desired outcome by somehow dynamically get value for the Criteria1 if I can make the macro understand what each shape (I have 12 atm) has a name and based on what is clicked that name should be the value for Criteria1. It's really hard to explain this I guess, I'm just a beginner at this, or not even that.

Comment: I did explain that in my comment I thought - all shapes call the same sub, and in that sub you get the name of the clicked shape (or the text contained in the shape) and pass it in as `Criteria1`

Comment: @TimWilliam, I understand your logic, makes sense, but I lack the skill to write it out in code! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested and works for me:

```vb
Sub SortExportSelected()
    
    Dim txt, ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, rVis As Range, wsName As String
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 'or ThisWorkbook
    
    'get the text from the clicked-on shape
    txt = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TextFrame2.TextRange.Text
    
    wsName = "R11 (P3)" & " fram t.o.m. " & Format(Now - 1, "YYYY-MM-DD")
    'if a sheet with this name already exists, delete it
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next 'ignore error if no matched sheet
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsName).Delete
    On Error GoTo 0      'stop ignoring errors
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets("PR11_P3")) 'get reference to the added sheet
    ws.Name = wsName
    
    With wb.Worksheets("PR11_P3").ListObjects("PR11_P3_Tabell")
         .Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=txt   'use `txt` for filtering
         .Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ws.Range("A1")
    End With
    
    With ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion, , xlYes)
            .Range.EntireColumn.AutoFit
            .Name = "PR11_P3_Temp_Tabell"
    End With

    With wb.Worksheets("PR11_P3")
        .Select
        .Range("A10").Select
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This is giving me test empty variant/empty and ws nothing workseet and Table Nothing ListObject

Comment: Edited to tidy up a little, but basic functionality unchanged.  Are you saying nothing happens  when you run this?

Comment: oh well, now it works but this happens: Its sorting after the "clicked name" but then it copy all rows and columns/entire table from sheet one(PR11_P#) and then its creating one sheet and sets as last sheets, dose copy table from first sheets to last sheet(as mentioned) puts this from A10(instead of A1),and then makes a new table in A1

Comment: So I saved below code and saved all the changes and so, after restarting excel this happens:```With ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion, , xlYes)
            .Name = "PR11_P3_Temp_Tabell"
            'this copys all data from sheet PR11_PS with table "PR11_P3_Tablell" isntead of just th sorted data form the table, how can I sort this issue?
    End With```

Comment: I made a few final edits (including fixing the A1/A10 which was there in your posted code, so I'd assume that was a typo?).  Works fine for me in testing.

Comment: Hi Tim, I'm trying to write a bit of code to get around the situation when the worksheet 'PR 11 (P3) fram t.o.m. 2022-05-01' is created and user by accident presses another text box that will try to generate same sheet.  At the moment if there sheet is there then I get an error on the line ws.Name = "R11 (P3)" & " fram t.o.m. " & Format(Now - 1, "YYYY-MM-DD") cause the sheet already exists, would it be possible to delete sheet if its created, first before generating on click on the different boxes?

Comment: If ws.Name <> "PR11_P3" Then
                ws.Delete
            Else: ws.Name = "R11 (P3)" & " fram t.o.m. " & Format(Now - 1, "YYYY-MM-DD")
        End If

Comment: But when I write it in that manner I get other errors, like on range.specialcells and copy command

Comment: See edit above to delete any sheet with the same name before adding the new one.

Comment: Thank you! I think I understand the difference between this approach rather the if one is that this allows workbook have more sheets then just the main one and the one generated from this and the textbox click action.